# Laravel 4 Natural Language Full-Text Searches MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('word')

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

It's very easy to search in laravel 4 with MYSQL LIKE searches.

```
Article::where('title', 'like', '%first%');
```

But, what would be the best way to use MYSQL Natural Language Full-Text Search?

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('first');
```

Anybody that has tried to do this in laravel?

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
Article::whereRaw("MATCH(title,body) AGAINST(?)", array('first'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality had been removed from Laravel 4 (It was there in Laravel 3).

However you can easily re-implement it as described here: http://creative-punch.net/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search/